# Get value of hidden field in Grid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radgrid, hidden-field

I have a RadGrid which produces the following html (hidden ID changes per row):

```
<input id="hiddenID" type="hidden" value="c6be9aaf-fc2b-441b-886e-120cfd6a73ee5" name="gvClaimDtSentDate$ctl00$ctl18$Detail50$ctl04$hiddenID">
<a id="c6be9aaf-fc2b-441b-886e-120cfd6a73ee" class="viewBtn" href="#">View</a>
<a class="orderBtn" id="lnkOrder" href="#">My Order</a>
```

I want to get the hidden ID of a raw on click of lnkOrder. so I have done below but it doesn't work as it gives me the static/same id for each row:

```
$('.orderBtn').click(function() {

            var tr = $("#<%=gvDtSentDate.ClientID%> tr");
            var id = tr.find("input[name$=hiddenID]").val();
```

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.orderBtn').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // gets closest parent tr element to the a
    var id = $tr.find("input[name$=hiddenID]").val();
    // if hidden input is the only one in the row you could simplify this to:
    // var id = $tr.find("input").val();
});
```